# Create FileStreamResultfrom HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, httphandler

I'm trying to hack into an external HttpHandler to return a FileStreamResult in my MVC application. I want to be able to have a clickable link and I'd rather not use JavaScript.

The path is correct, I can call the path directly in the browser; I just get the following error:

> The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

I can call the path directly in the browser.

My code so far:

```
    public FileStreamResult Test()
    {
        Uri uri = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url;
        string leftPart = uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority);
        Uri cssUri = new Uri(leftPart + "/css.axd?path=test.css");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(cssUri);
        using (Stream stream = request.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
        {
            return new FileStreamResult(stream, "text/css")
                       {
                           FileDownloadName = "test.css"
                       };
        }

    }
```

Does anyone have any pointers they can give me to show where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're disposing the stream immediately after the return because of the using statement... So you're returning a closed stream to be read which will undoubtedly throw an unhandled exception.

Comment: I'm gonna go and bang my head against a wall now. So obvious!